# Protocol init not found if generic class requires subclass

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I've  created a small example with generics logic and I don't understand what this error means. I think there is some problem with *designated initializer*.

Hope someone has already handled it and can explain it to me.

```
protocol Test {
    init(value: Int)
}

class ClassTest<T: Test> where T: UIView {
    var t: T

    init() {
        t = T(value: 2) //error:
    }
}
```

gives the following *compiler error*:

> Argument labels '(value:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: I tested [your code on Swift 3.1](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/591eb9b830a8725adaecdfd0) and it worked fine ;)

Comment: Why you have added `where T: UIView` ? If it's a UIView class, you need to implement the init(coder:) that's why you are getting error

Comment: @PauloMattos try to check it in Xcode :)

Comment: @PauloMattos The class needs to inherit from another class in order to reproduce: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/591ebcdaa1cd601a30972e69

Comment: @MidhunMP because I want to have a property of type `UIView<Test>` and initialize this one within parent's `init` method with custom parameters.

Comment: This is a bug that has already been filed, see [SR-3837](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3837)

Comment: Is this a good idea to have a constructor in a protocol, in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

This bug is already opened in Swift Jira :( - https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3837

Answer (score 2):

Try this *hack* for now:

```
class ClassTest<T: Test> where T: UIView {
    var t: T
    init() {
        // t = T(value: 2) // Compiler error!
        t = create()
    }
}

func create<T: Test>() -> T {
    return T(value: 2)  
}
```

I guess having one *less* constraint to worry about gets the compiler going :-)

---

**Compiler still broken?** Check if [this code compiles successfully](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/591f333e6a5d0224544c436b) to know if this bug has been fixed already.